# How do I retain parameters after a form validation fails in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, parameters

I am creating an application which tracks signatures form various organizations.  I have a simple form which I can pass an ID to, so it will automatically select the right organization.   The URL for add looks like this:

```
/signatures/add/3
```

The form works well.  By passing 3, or any other ID, it automatically selects the right field, because in my view I do:

```
echo $form->input('organization_id', array('selected' => $this->passedArgs));
```

I run into my problem when the user forgets to fill out a form element.  The form returns the user to:

```
/signatures/add/
```

So it doesn't have the right organization selected.  It reverts to the default which is 1.  Any tips on how I can retain my parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about cake but it looks like the action of the form is /signatures/add/

If you add the id to the form action so it reads action="signatures/add/{ID}" in the view it should go back to that organizations page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Galen.  You actually pointed me in the right direction.  I realized that my form wanted to save the state of the organization, but I over-wrote it when I did this:

```
echo $form->input('organization_id', array('selected' => $this->passedArgs));
```

So what I do now instead is:

```
if (!empty($this->passedArgs)) {
            echo $form->input('organization_id', array('selected' => $this->passedArgs));
        } else {
            echo $form->input('organization_id');
        }
```

And it does the trick.

Comment: Although this will work as expected, I'd recommend using named params for optional params. When I see "/signatures/add/3" I don't really know what "3" is. If it were "/signatures/add/organization:3" it is much clearer. Not to mention how this will make your life easier if you ever decide to pass more params: "/signatures/add/organization:3/type:2". Take a look at the cake docs for more info if you haven't used named params before.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set the organization_id to the selected value is to include it in your data array in your controller. Eg

```
function add($organization_id)
  if(!empty($this->data)) {
    if($this->Signature->save($this->data)) {
      $this->setFlash('Save successful')
      $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'))
    } else {
      $this->setFlash('Please review the form for errors')
    }
  }

  if($organization_id) {
    $this->data['Signature']['organization_id'] = $organization_id;
  }
}
```

Then in your view simply put

```
echo $form->create('Signature', array('action' => 'add'))
echo $form->input('organization_id')
```

and it will automatically insert the organization_id value from the the controllers data.